# separate log file for exception

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j

My web application is running in tomcat 6. Currently all my log.info statements are added to catalina.out. Is there any way so that when an exception occurs it should go to my custom file called applicationExceptions.log file?

Answer (score 0):

Update `log4j.properties` with the following and check.

```
# add an extra category to a log file 
log4j.category.yourPackage=ERROR,ERR
# Skip to write default logger 
log4j.additivity.yourPackage=false

# ERR is set to be a FileAppender which will log Error actions in the application.     
log4j.appender.ERR=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.ERR.Threshold=ERROR 
log4j.appender.ERR.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout       
log4j.appender.ERR.file=logs/error.log
```

Comment: Hi, The problem is that my application is already having log.info. I tried its not working